# An equilateral triangle altitude measurements.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

An equilateral triangle has three equal sides and if I take per example 11 as the side of the triangle then $11\times3=33$ for the perimeter.I want to find the height or the altitude of the geometric figure called a triangle.
So I came up with the result which is$\sqrt\frac{11\times11\times3}{4}$ or a result $\frac{11\sqrt3}{2}$
Why do we use only $\frac{11\sqrt3}{2}$ as the height?

Answer (score 0):

or, in other words; the altitude is $a \cos \left( \dfrac{\pi}{3}\right)$, where $a$ is the edge length.

[image]

You have the $\angle BAC = \frac{\pi}{3}$. By trigonometry, you have: $ \dfrac{h}{a} = \cos{\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}\right)}$

Comment: I don't understand why$a\cos\frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: @user274872 Added an image.

Comment: Thank you now I understand the measurements.I was not using the triangle in radian mode.